# yyyy-mm-dd is not parsed correctly by phpexcel toArray

Tags: php, phpexcel

In Excel, the cell value is '2015-06-10' (formatted as Short Date). When PHPExcel read the file and convert to array. The value becomes '06-10-15'. I cant find a way to convert it to '2015-06-10'

```
// load xlsx
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($model->file->tempName);

// convert xlsx to array
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

dump($sheetData);
```

Comment: Without seeing the file itself, I would guess that it's using one of Excel's "locale specific" date formats. As PHPExcel is not locale-aware, it uses a default format

Comment: I am using Excel for Mac (Version 15.36). please the sample file https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvmrlvni7rohkd5/Workbook2-date-test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: The sheet looks to be M/D/YYYY Instead of yyyy/mm/dd and has the locale set to U.S. standard.